# No matching client found for package name for new Firebase project

Tags: android, firebase

I've switched out my `google-services.json` file because I want to connect to a different firebase project. When I try to build again it falls on

```
No matching client found for package name 'com.foresight.app
```

My android manifest contains

```
package="com.foresight.app">
```

My new firebase project has a package name `com.foresight.app.dev`

Not sure how to get app to recognise the new project...

Comment: Why is the package name different in SDK Configuration on Firebase and in your app?

Comment: It's a different firebase project

Comment: But I think that this doesn't affect your package name? Just remove the app from the old project and add it to the new project. The same way you did with the first. The package name must be the same as in the app. Or you can simply now change the package name of the app.

Comment: Did you add the app to your new project in Project Settings in Firebase?

Comment: Yeah the app is added. That's where I got the service.json file. I can't remove the app from the old project. I'll be using it again. It's connected to a prod environment. The new firebase project is being used as a dev environment. Probably have to change the package name in Android Manifest?

Comment: I'll post you an answer on how to do this

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the package name, here is how to do it. First right-click on the `java` folder on the left side where your classes are:

[image]

---

Select to add a new package and then on the next screen pick something like `...\app\src\main\java`

[image]

---

Next, there will be a popup, just write the name of the new package, in your case it is `com.foresight.app.dev`. This will create a new package inside the java folder on the left side.

[image]

---

Now just select all of your classes and drag them to the last folder in your new package. Or you can select all of them and *RightClick > Refactor > Move* and select *To Package* on the 3 dots on the right side. Find your last package folder and press OK

[image]

---

Now just press `Refactor` and delete your old package folders. Now inside `AndroidManifest.xml` change your packate to that same name. Also do this inside build.gradle and Sync:

[image]

---

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.foresight.app.dev">
```